# compile .net-core 1.1.0 app against 4.6.x

Tags: asp.net-core

trying to compile my asp.netcore 1.1 app against .net framework 4.6.x
my project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "imports": [
      "dotnet5.6",
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "net462": {
  }
},
```

but then package restore complains with:

```
Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there was a section before the frameworks-section which was still "hardcoded" to .netcore framework. i've just removed that and it worked

Comment: may i ask why the -1?

Answer (score 1):

Your framework section should look like this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
}
```

or here is complete template for project.json for asp.net core on net461
You can create this type of project in Visual Studio by selecting New Project|Visual C#|Windows|Web|ASP.NET Core Web Application (.Net Framework)

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: using the

  `"frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },`
i now get:

    `Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 is not compatible with net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1). Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1.`